# How to get tree node div element using this id,ext:tree-node-id="BSMNode1"

Tags: extjs

In Extjs 3,Ext.tree.TreePanel,the tree nodes are getting generated with such type of id ext:tree-node-id="BSMNode1" inside a div element.How to get the div element using the id.I have tried Ext.getCmp('BSMNode1') and $j('#BSMNode1').But,unable to get the element.Please help me on this.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ExtJs 3. (I've posted this as an answer since it contains a solution). I wanted to add the class 'deleted' to this div.

```
    <div ext:tree-node-id="web_6972" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf x-unselectable x-tree-node-leaf unpublished psave pview pedit pduplicate pnew pnew_modDocument pnew pnew_modSymLink pnew pnew_modWebLink pnew pnew_modStaticResource pqcreate pqupdate pdelete pundelete ppublish punpublish"
unselectable="on" id="extdd-277"><span class="x-tree-node-indent"><img alt="" src="/addons/manager/assets/ext3/resources/images/default/s.gif" class="x-tree-elbow-line"></span><i class="x-tree-ec-icon x-tree-elbow-end"></i><i class="icon tree-resource icon-web-6972 icon-parent-web-6971"
  unselectable="on" id="extdd-278"></i><a hidefocus="on" class="x-tree-node-anchor" href="#" tabindex="1"><span unselectable="on" id="extdd-279">CanDelete <span dir="ltr">(6972)</span></span></a></div>
```

Here is the JS

```
var x = Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('#web_6972'); // undefined
```

What did work for me was to get a reference to the tree itself (higher up) and do this:

```
 var rTree = Ext.getCmp('modx-resource-tree');
 var tNode = rTree.getNodeById('web_6972');
 tNode.getUI().addClass('deleted');
```

Answer (score -1):

`Ext.getCmp()`  is used to select an ExtJS component, to select DOM element use [Ext.DomQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery).

`Ext.DomQuery.selectNode('#BSMNode1');`

Comment: @bob-ray, what is your ExtJS version? Could you provide fiddle to illustrate your issue? `Ext.DomQuery` is proper way to select DOM elements with ExtJS 3 in general.